# Langchain cannot create index when running inside Django server

Tags: django, langchain, gpt4all

I have a simple Langchain chatbot using GPT4ALL that's being run in a singleton class within my Django server.

Here's the simple code:

```py
gpt4all_path = './models/gpt4all_converted.bin'
llama_path = './models/ggml_model_q4_0.bin'

embeddings = LlamaCppEmbeddings(model_path=llama_path)

print("Initializing Index...")
vectordb = FAISS.from_documents(docs, embeddings)
print("Initialzied Index!!!")
```

This code runs fine when used inside the manage.py shell separately but the class instantiation fails to create a FAISS index with the same code. It keeps printing the `llama_print_timings   43000ms` with the ms increasing on every print message.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: first does the same thing workds outside django for example in script?
if it works in script then you should be using *Celery* for this such big task when dealing in django to. 
https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html

Comment: Celery is not what I needed for this... I just changed it to Chroma from FAISS and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to use Chroma instead of FAISS for some reason. I still don't understand it because it honestly doesn't make sense but it works. I'll update this answer when I can and when I really figure it out but for those who run into something similar in the future and can't find a solution, try Chroma instead of FAISS.